# How to fetch all image names?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to fetch all image names that are in one folder.

What I want to do is, I put all images in a folder named:"Files"

*Now is that possible to add all image names to an array, So i dont need to write all images name manually to array or is there any other simple way to do this?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSArray *dirlist;

path= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath],@"Folder_Name"];

    filemgr =[NSFileManager defaultManager];

dirlist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];

NSString *directory =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",path,[dirlist objectAtIndex: index]] ;

NSLog(@"Path:%@",directory);
NSArray *temp = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:NULL];
```

Note : When you add your image's folder in project , please remember to select " Create folder reference " option.

Use this Whole image path:

```
    imagesUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int j =0; j< [temp count]; j++) 
    {
        [imagesUrls addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",directory,[temp objectAtIndex:j]]];

    }
```

Finally use imagesUrls array to get the path of image.

```
imageView.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagesUrls objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Comment: /MyApp.app has not contained any of my files, it shows all images in one.

Comment: i didn't get you . please again explain me

Comment: When I got to bundlePath and show package contents ,it contains only images not my folder where I stored it.

Comment: All folders are removed during packaging. Your xcode or filesystem files do not exist in the bundle anymore.

Comment: I'm getting all names, but why I can't use that image? When I set images to UIImageView it's not working.

Comment: See , i update my answer .If you are satisfy with my answer then give me up point.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *filelist= [filemanager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:filePath error:&error];
```

Here `filePath` is the path to your "Files" folder, and the above method returns the array of file names present in the given directory.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to saif's answer you can filter the result with a predicate

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self endswith '.jpg'"];
NSArray *jpgImages = [filelist filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

Comment: but i need some of images names that i placed in folder.